# .next folder size increases in Next react App

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

We have developed the nextjs react application, which is ready in production now. It leads to some storage issues. we inspect a lot and finally found .next folder size increases while we navigate to some pages. For example, the .next folder size was too small for the initial build, like 6.4Mb. After some page route happens, it will be like 256Mb.

can someone explain the cause of this issue?

How to fix this storage issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you pages generated? Do you use SSG with Incremental Static Regeneration? Can you reproduce the issue locally when running the app in production mode (`next build && next start`)?

Comment: We used some static pages and Server-side rendering pages. The issue remains the same when the production build in the local environment. @juliomalves